# Is this assumption unnecessary? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

There is the following theorem in this book:

> Theorem 11.3(p.96):
>   Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f : Q \to \mathbb{R}$; assume $f$ is integrable over $Q$.
>   (a) If $f$ vanishes except on a set of measure zero, then $\int_Q f = 0$.
>   (b) If $f$ is non-negative and if $\int_Q f = 0$, then $f$ vanishes except on a set of measure zero.

I think we don't need to assume that $f$ is integrable over $Q$.

Since $f$ vanishes except on a set of measure zero, $f$ is a bounded continuous function except on a set of measure zero. So, $f$ is integrable over $Q$.
So, I think we don't need to assume that $f$ is integrable over $Q$ for (a).

When we write $\int_Q f$, we already assume that $f$ is integrable over $Q$.
So, I think we don't need to assume that $f$ is integrable over $Q$ for (b).

Am I right or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right when you state that if $f$ vanishes except on a set of measure zero, then $f$ is integrable. But if you don't say that $f$ is integrable, then it doesn't make sense to talk about $\int_Qf$. Yes, if $f$ wasn't integrable, this wouldn't make sense, but it is not a good idea to leave those assumptions implicit.

Comment: Thank you very much again, Jose Carlos Santos.